# Electron React upload image from USB Path only

Tags: html, reactjs, electron

html input file attribute open file choosing in computer and can see all folder, can it customized to only open specific path like USB(cannot open other folder).

Comment: Are you asking to default to or to restrict to? Do you want to do it by path (known beforehand) or to actually detect USB devices?

Comment: This is my app feature that I 've already done
- My app can detect USB, and can show a list of plugged USB

I want my app to
- When choosing for upload a photo, videos, etc, I want it restricted only for usb path. If the USB is not plugged, it must not show path for other folder.

Sorry for the bad english